# The mysqli class from php does not load, sporadically

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel

For some time now, my server with centos6 and cpanel, is giving me the following error, randomly and from time to time, at least 2 or 3 times a day.

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/.../db.driver.mysqli.php:100
```

The problem is that php is well configured, and the web works, I only get this error sporadically.
I find out, because I have a function reading the error_log file, and it sends me the errors by mail every 5 minutes.
I can't understand how it can only happen from time to time, and I can't reproduce the error by hand.
La linea que produce el error, simplemente dice:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli(...);
```

Installed packages:
**Apache 2.4**

- config
- config-runtime
- devel
- mod_asis
- mod_authn_anon
- mod_authn_socache
- mod_bwlimited
- mod_cgid
- mod_deflate
- mod_env
- mod_expires
- mod_headers
- mod_http2
- mod_mpm_worker
- mod_proxy
- mod_proxy_ajp
- mod_proxy_fcgi
- mod_proxy_http
- mod_proxy_wstunnel
- mod_security2
- mod_ssl
- mod_suexec
- mod_unique_id
- mod_version
- tools

**PHP 7.3**

- libc-client
- pear
- php-bcmath
- php-calendar
- php-cli
- php-common
- php-curl
- php-devel
- php-fileinfo
- php-fpm
- php-ftp
- php-gd
- php-iconv
- php-imap
- php-litespeed
- php-mbstring
- php-mysqlnd
- php-opcache
- php-pdo
- php-posix
- php-soap
- php-sockets
- php-xml
- php-zip
- runtime

**Additional Packages**

- apr
- apr-devel
- apr-util
- apr-util-devel
- brotli
- cpanel-tools
- documentroot
- libargon2
- libcurl
- libmcrypt
- libnghttp2
- libxml2
- modsec-sdbm-util
- nghttp2
- openssl
- openssl11
- php-cli
- php-cli-lsphp
- profiles-cpanel
- tomcat85

Comment: It may or may not be your case, but this is a common issue when URLs are called that don't invoke your auto loader. For instance, if you have a template called `404.php` and your code expects that file to be loaded from a router, everything works. But if someone (usually a bot) discovers that URL and tries to access it directly, these kind of errors can pop up. It is very common in the WordPress world where bots are constantly hitting known URLs, so a lot of files include a check for a known WordPress constant to determine if they were accessed correctly.

Comment: It's not the case. All the files and routed links works fine. I have some reports of users having http 500, and looking at the timestamp, it matches the errors in the log.

Comment: You could try disabling opcache to see if there's a bug in there, but I haven't heard of anything. Does your code use `require` or `include` **at all** besides a **single central file** that uses a PSR autoloader?

Comment: thank you, I will try disabling the opcache and wait to see if any error ocurrs. PHP-FPM is disabled, so opcache doesn't work really. When I enable php-fpm on the account, the website stops running after a few request, and have to reestart php-fpm. Then, I have left disabled php-fpm. I will try re-compile easyapache without opcache and see what happens. Maybe I will upgrade php 7.3 to 7.4 in the proccess.